# android repeatedly play a mp3 file without any gap

Tags: java, android, audio, android-mediaplayer, soundpool

I want to play a mp3 file from sdcard repeatedly without any gap. I am using `MediaPlayer.setlooping(true)` method to repeatedly play the **mp3**. it works fine. But it gives a gape of few seconds between repetition. I also looking for soundPools but it also give some gap. So is there any class, method or some idea that help me to eliminate the gap of few seconds.

Comment: might also be duplicate <a href="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14080793/my-background-loop-music-doesnt-loop-good" >My background loop music doesn't “loop” good</a>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After doing some handy experiments at last i got my solution using

`mPlayer.setLooping(true);`

mPlayer is an instance of MediaPlayer class. Although this line of code looping the code but this have a few gap between consecutive sounds. However finally it works for me. Any one can give a try to MediaPlayer class. its really awesome for handling audio file.

Answer (score 0):

I think thats not possible, but you can try to implement fade-in and fade-out methods. Check this link:

[How to create fade-in/fade-out sound effects for any music file that my app plays?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6885162/3377857)

***EDIT:*** Or try this, i guess this should work: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13410499/3377857

Comment: I appreciate you answer. But i didn't want to fade in-out my sound. I just want to eliminate the gap between repetition. I will try to do this if i did't get any kinds of solution. Thanks.

Comment: thanks Morbe for your answer, its really a well resource but i have to use mp3 file, i could not use .ogg file format.